# Cant Stop event listener in Array tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant remove eventlistener in an array tag when I try a lot of thing but cant accomplished anything, so at last I prefer to write down here.. Please does anyone have any idea?

I create "a" tags and than I click on one of them than bacground colors start to change but than I want to stop when I push "end" button but the problem is it never stops always continue...

Here is What I tried yet.... (Please check it in big screen)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.createElement("A");
  btn.innerHTML = "CLICK ME TO START<br> EVENTLISTENER";
  btn.style.marginLeft = "20px";
  btn.className = "formulbitti boya ";
  document.getElementById("kanban").appendChild(btn);

  $(".formulbitti").click(function() {
    index_valbas = $(".formulbitti").index(this)
    $(".formulbitti").mouseover(function() {
      index_val = $(".formulbitti").index(this)
      elements = document.querySelectorAll('.formulbitti');
      elements.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('mouseover', denemefunc(index_val, index_valbas, elements));
      });
    });
    $(".sonlandir").click(function() {
      elements = document.querySelectorAll('.formulbitti');
      elements.forEach(element => {
        element.removeEventListener('mouseover', denemefunc);
      });
    });
  });
  alert(deneme);
}

function denemefunc(index_val, index_valbas, elements) {
  var classesName = $('.formulbitti')[index_val].className;
  classlists = document.getElementsByClassName("formulbitti").length;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < classlists) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("formulbitti")[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,255, 1)";
    i = i + 1;
  };

  document.getElementsByClassName("formulbitti")[index_valbas].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(220, 220, 220, 1)";
  var i = index_valbas;
  while (i < index_val + 1) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("formulbitti")[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(220, 220, 220, 1)";
    i = i + 1;
  };
  alert(deneme);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>I can start eventlistener but cant finish it with </p>
<div id="kanban">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</div>
<button class="sonlandir">end</button>
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to provide a clearer description of the issue and your goal. Currently it's not clear what you're trying to do. Also note that the snippet generates several errors.

Comment: Errors is because I added "alert (undefiened)" to stop javascript of repeatations...

Comment: Rory I edited question with more details

Comment: You never set an event listener to start with. `element.addEventListener('mouseover', denemefunc(index_val, index_valbas, elements));` assigns the return value of `denemefunc` to be used as the event listener. Since `denemefunc` does not return anything there is no event listener set.

Comment: how will I transport the datas what I want to other "denemefunc" and also I tried that too and doesnt work again...

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is that you never actually add any event listeners. `addEventListener()` expects a function as second argument. Yet you pass `denemefunc(index_val, index_valbas, elements)`. Although `denemefunc` is a function, by adding `(index_val, index_valbas, elements)` you directly invoke the function thus passing the return value (which is `undefined`).

To have each `.formulbitti` element call `denemefunc` with different parameters you should create callbacks for each element and store them (so you can remove the event listeners later). Then add an event listener for each element passing the callback you created.

The snippet below should give you an idea of how handle the addition and remove of a list of event listeners. This snippet is a bit verbose and might be further simplified.

```js
const $formulbittis = $(".formulbitti");
let callbacks = null;

$("#set-events").on("click", function () {
  // prevent adding multiple event listeners to a single element
  if (callbacks) return;
  
  // create and store callbacks
  callbacks = $formulbittis.map(function (index, element) {
    return (event) => denemefunc(index, element);
  });
  
  // add event listeners
  $formulbittis.each(function (index, element) {
    element.addEventListener("mouseover", callbacks[index]);
  });
});

$("#del-events").on("click", function () {
  // no callbacks means there is nothing to remove
  if (!callbacks) return;
  
  // remove event listeners
  $formulbittis.each(function (index, element) {
    element.removeEventListener("mouseover", callbacks[index]);
  });
  
  // clear callbacks array
  callbacks = null;
});

function denemefunc(index, element) {
  console.log(index, element);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="set-events" type="button">set event listeners</button>
<button id="del-events" type="button">delete event listeners</button>

<ul>
  <li class="formulbitti">one</li>
  <li class="formulbitti">two</li>
  <li class="formulbitti">three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the main problem for eventlstener is inside another function is that : 

  var btn = document.createElement("A");
  btn.className = "formulbitti boya ";  (classname function doesnt call the function)

Comment: if you dont want to be inside create button function please tell me how can "classname" calls after new creations

Comment: your aasnwer is just for a simple eventlistener, the problem is here eventlistener in deep of function cause of createelement